# Why adding `frozen=True` to dataclass makes it slower?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, python-dataclasses, slots

As above. In particular, I see that it is twice as slow. I would have thought it makes things faster.

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = """
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)  # repeat with False
class A:
    a: int = 1
    b: int = 1
"""

code = """
obj = A(3, 2)
"""

print(f"{timeit(code, setup, number=1000_000)=}")
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [frozen instances](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dataclasses.html#frozen-instances):

> There is a tiny performance penalty when using `frozen=True`: `__init__()` cannot use simple assignment to initialize fields, and must use `object.__setattr__()`.

Comment: Aside from init, is it any faster in access?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference besides `__init__`, except for being frozen. But you should test it.